# Proper punctuation in direct speech quotations

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

Do I need the colon right after the word `восклицал` and the comma right after `смысла!"`?

> А когда Виктор **восклицал:** "Здесь нету никакого **смысла!",** или "Где
>   здесь смысл?!", то он, конечно, не вкусы имел в виду.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> А когда Виктор восклицал: "Здесь нету никакого смысла!" или
> "Где здесь смысл?!" — то он, конечно, не вкусы имел в виду.

The colon is indeed needed to introduce the direct speech.

The comma is not needed, since the coordinate pieces of direct speech are linked by a single conjunction ***или***.

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm#%D0%B7_04)

A dash instead of a comma is recommended after the second piece of direct speech because it ends in an exclamation mark:

> И только когда он шептал: ***«Мама! Мама!» – ему становилось как будто легче...*** (Чехов) (прямая речь заканчивается восклицательным знаком)

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/52.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think you can safely leave both out:

А когда Виктор восклицал "Здесь нету никакого смысла!" или "Где здесь смысл?!", то он, конечно, не вкусы имел в виду.

...looks completely benign to my eyes. Provided this is supposed to be a modern piece of writing, with modern punctuation.

Comment: How do you define "modern punctuation"?

Comment: Whatever is used by educated people on LiveJournal, for example, but still reflects speech a bit more.